# request.getRemoteAddr(); returns 127.0.0.1 in jboss6 and in wildfly10 it returns actual remote ip

Tags: jboss6.x, wildfly-10

I am migrating jboss6 to wildfly10, somewhere in code i am checking request.getRemoteAddr(); in jboss6 it returns 127.0.0.1, but in wildfly10 it returns the actual remote ip of client. But i want to know the logic behind that, or achive the same in wildfly10.
Thanks
Pavan